# How to animate underline on text on hover AND keep the line on mouse out

Tags: html, css, animation, less

I've seen a lot of question and tutorials on how to animate a line, but they don't seem to fix my issue.
I have a text with an already underline, so I want the user to hover under on the div that contains the text and have the line animate left to right but keep the line afterwards.

This is the code that I have at the moment but its very glitch and the border bottom and :after dont work well together because they are at different height

```
.cta-text{
    color: #2980FF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2980FF;
    transition: width .2s;
    
    &:hover{
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 0;
        height: 3px;
        display: block;
        background: #2980FF;
    }

    &:hover::after {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -2px;
        transition: width .3s;
    }
}
```

Here's a codepen example https://codepen.io/godhandkiller/pen/jOrVjdq

Comment: I can help if you share the missing codes.

Comment: What missing codes? everything I have is on the codepen link @KaanDemir

Answer (score -1):

Use **@keyframes** to change/pause animation.

```css
@keyframes hover {
 0% {
   // normal styles
 }
 100% {
   // hover styles
 }
}

.class {
 animation-name: hover;
 animation-duration: 1ms;
 animation-fill-mode: backwards;
 animation-play-state: paused;      
 }

.class:active,
.class:focus,
.class:hover {
   //hover style you define
 }
```

Use [this link](http://codepen.io/morewry/full/GLjpK) to see an example.